# What's the difference between mass spectrometry, mass spectroscopy, and mass spectrography?

Tags: mass-spectrometry

It seems that the terms mass spectrometry, mass spectroscopy, and mass spectrography are mostly used like synonyms. Is this correct? Or is there a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Encyclopaedia Britannica](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/368325/mass-spectrometry#ref619843), mass spectrographs use(d) photographic plates or films for the detection of ions, as in the apparatus thought out by [F. W. Aston](http://www-outreach.phy.cam.ac.uk/camphys/massspectrograph/massspectrograph_index.htm) in 1919.